# how to clone a sqlite database structure without copying data (windows)

Tags: database, sqlite, schema, clone

I have a sqlite database mydatabase.sqlite. I want to create a new database copy.sqlite with the same tables but without copying data. Some time ago I found a way to do that using .schema command and redirection, and it worked fine but now I can't remember that command anymore. I got crazy searching here the solution but didn't find it. Can you help me, please? Thx.

Answer (score 3):

After several attempts and research I came up with this solution. It is not as simple as the one I found time ago but it seems work fine. This is a sequence of commands to type in the prompt of sqlite3. (The procedure I can't remember was just a line long, to type in directly in the Windows prompt.)

```
sqlite> .open mydatabase.sqlite    # open mydatabase.sqlite database
sqlite> .output schema.sql         # redirect output to file schema.sql
sqlite> .schema                    # write schema of mydatabase.sqlite to file schema.sql

sqlite> .open copy.sqlite          # create new empty database
sqlite> .read schema.sql           # copy the structure of mydatabase.sqlite (= schema.sql) to copy.sqlite
```

The last command gives the following error:

```
Error: near line 2: object name reserved for internal use: sqlite_sequence
```

but the new database is created as well and it seams to work fine.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, though it took me some time to understand how the sqlite commands worked together! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
sqlite3 mydatabase.sqlite ".schema --nosys" | sqlite3 copy.sqlite
```

should do it for many cases. If you have virtual tables with backing shadow tables (Like FTS ones), those might cause errors.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried it but it does just nothing. When I type the command you suggested, I get just the prompt. No copy.sqlite database was created.

Comment: @bells You're doing this at a shell prompt, right? Not in the sqlite3 program.

Comment: Yes, I did it in windows 10 prompt

Comment: I opened a windows shell, got to the directory where are located sqlite3.exe file and the mydatabase.sqlite file, then typed your command. But i got back just the prompt.

Comment: Oh, windows? No idea about that. It works in a bash/zsh/ksh/etc. prompt.

Comment: Oh I see. Not using Linux. Thank you very much as well.

Comment: --nosys was added in sqlite3 version 3.34.0, so in earlier version this won't work and result in empty output.